# How to enable auto-revert-mode for files under a certain directory

Tags: auto-revert-mode, directory-local-variables

I have my org files kept synchronized via rsync with various devices. These buffers are usually open in any running emacs instances due to agenda and capture. I want emacs to re-read these files from disk when something arrives via rsync. I know that `auto-revert-mode` handles this, but I want to enable it solely for files under my org directory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Funny: it looks like you choose a tag that directly answers your question ("`directory-local-variables`")

The best way to accomplish this is by placing a `.dir-locals.el` file in your org directory and using it to enable `auto-revert-mode`. Specifically, the file should look contain this:

```
((nil . ((eval . (auto-revert-mode 1)))))
```

If you want only `org` files to auto-revert, change `nil` to `org-mode`.

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html):

> Sometimes, you may wish to define the same set of local variables to all the files in a certain directory and its subdirectories, such as the directory tree of a large software project. This can be accomplished with directory-local variables.
>
> The usual way to define directory-local variables is to put a file named .dir-locals.el in a directory. Whenever Emacs visits any file in that directory or any of its subdirectories, it will apply the directory-local variables specified in .dir-locals.el, as though they had been defined as file-local variables for that file

Please see [the manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) for more information.

Comment: That's because I knew what to look for, but I couldn't find a variable to set. Of course, what I was missing was `eval`. Thanks!